# Uploading a file to shopify with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, file-upload, shopify

I am having difficulty uploading files to shopify using selenium .. Selenium can't seem to find the input element I need to add my file to, I'm assuming it's to do with the input type=hidden part? See image.

[image]

I have tried a bunch of variations like this

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='files_']"))).send_keys("DIR/myfile.pdf')
```

and tried to execute a scrip to try unhide the input

```
container = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='hidden']")
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].type = 'text';", container)
```

etc etc

The documentations for shopifyapi aren't the greatest, and I'm not the best coder. Any help woul dbe apprecitated. 
Thanks!

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: if you click on upload files manually are go getting browser popup to upload files? then try all input/label their. it may help

Comment: selenium can't see the button code to click it, and manually clicking it brings it out of the DOM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To upload file you have to send keys to the `input` with type `file`, generally it hidden. Replace `element_to_be_clickable` with `presence_of_element_located` and try to send keys like in code below:

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#files_"))).send_keys("DIR/myfile.pdf')
```

Comment: You my sir are a legend, thanks so much it's been driving me crazy! Will have to remember that CSS_selector call.